# NetBeans 7 to MS Sql Server 2008R2 Connection

Tags: sql-server, netbeans, database-connection

I'm looking for an easy way to connect my NetBeans application to an SQLServer 2008 R2 database...
I tried with JDBC:ODBC but this doesn't work... I tried other ways but appears to be deprecated or too old for the jre 1.7...

Does anybody have any suggestion? I'm googlig for hours but nobody talks about it, the only things i found are about SQL Server 2000 an other ancient systems!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official [Microsoft JDBC Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21599) or the [JTDS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/) open source driver each of these two works fine ...

Comment: I've already downloaded and JDBC driver but when i go to the wizard of netbeans for the creation of a DB Application he cannot find my server, even if i give it the right address! Is there any SQL Server option to enable jdbc interaction?

Comment: No, just make sure to have SQL Browser service enabled.

Comment: Under SQLServer Configuration in Computer Management i have 3 services..
SQL Server - running
SQL Server Agent - stopped
SQL Server Browser - running

Answer (score 0):

Use jtds as the jdbc driver.. and here's some more fluff